# Counting the number of weakly separated pairs

Tags: co.combinatorics

Given two $k$-subsets $I$ and $J$ of $\{1 \dots n\}$, denote by $\min(J)$ the minimal element in $J$ and by $\max(I)$ the maximal element in $I$, we write $I \prec J$ if $\max(I)<\min(J)$. The sets $I$ and $J$ are called weakly separated if at least one of the
following two conditions holds:

(1) $J-I$ can be partitioned into a disjoint union $J-I = J' \sqcup J''$ so that $J' \prec I-J \prec J''$;

(2) $I-J$ can be partitioned into a disjoint union $I-J = I' \sqcup I''$ so that $I' \prec J-I \prec I''$.

This condition is introduced in Leclerc and Zelevinsky's paper [Quasi-commuting families of quantum minors](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869305002243).

Let $N$ be the number of all weakly separated pairs $I, J$ where $|I|=|J|=k$ and $I, J \subset {1, \ldots, n}.

I have counted certain special cases. In the case of $k=2$, $n$ arbitrary, $N$ is the number of diagonal dissections of an $n$-gon into two regions. In the case of $k=3, n=6$, $N=54$. In the case of $k=3, n=7$, $N=224$. In the case of $k=3,n=8$, $N=652$. In the case of $k=3,n=9$, $N=1557$.

Are there some method in combinatorics to count the number $N$? Thank you very much.

Edit: I forgot to say that I assume that $I \ne J$, $I$ and $J$ are not of the form $a, a+1, \ldots, a_k$ (mod $n$). I counted the pair $I, J$ as a set. So I counted $(I, J)$, $(J, I)$ as one pair (not two pairs). I am sorry about the confusion.

Comment: It's a certain binomial sum. You may write some generating function in a closed form. But not the entire sum, I am afraid.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: If we exclude $I=J$ case, and denote $|I-J|=|J-I|=s$, then if we fix the sets $I\cap J$ and $I\Delta J$ (that may be done by ${n\choose k-s,2s,n-k-s}$ ways), there are $2s$ choices of $I-J$. So the answer is $\sum_{s=1}^n 2s\cdot {n\choose k-s,2s,n-k-s}$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, thank you very much. What is the value of ${n \choose k-s,2s,n-k-s}$?

Comment: $n!/((k-s)!(2s)!(n-k-s)!)$

Comment: @FedorPetrov, thank you very much!

Comment: @FedorPetrov, I tried to verify your formula using some $k,n$. I think that in your formula, $s$ is from $1$ to $k$ (not $n$). But still in the case of $k=3, n=6$, I don't get $54$. Why there are $2s$ choices of $I-J$? Thank you very much.

Comment: because either $I-J$ or $J-I$ should be a segment of $s$ consecutive elements of $2s$ elements of $I\Delta J$

Comment: @FedorPetrov, thank you very much.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, now I see why my result is different from your formula. I forgot to say that I assumed that $I, J$ are not of the form $a, a+1, \ldots, a+k$ (mod $n$). I also counted $(I, J), (J, I)$ as one pair (not two pairs). Sorry about the confusion. I will edit the file.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, using your formula, the number is $\sum_{s=1}^k s {n \choose k-s, 2s, n-k-s} - {n \choose 2} - n {n \choose k} + n^2$. Thanks a lot!